# How to cat Bold

Tags: tinymce

```
     I have this as part of tinymce


   

  setup : function (ed) {
       ed.onKeyUp.add(
        function (ed, evt) {
            
            new_value = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
            
            new_value = new_value.replace(/,/g, "&#9728;"); 
            
            hidden_Field = ed.target.getAttribute("data-hidden")    
            
            $("#" + hidden_Field).val(new_value);   
        }
    );
```

It works perfectly when typing in something but how do I catch when someone say Bolds a word. Is there an equivalent on OnKeyUp.add as I can't find one. OnFocusOut doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an equivalent on OnKeyUp.add as I can't find one.

Solved. I needed `ed.onChange.add(` instead of `ed.onKeyUp.add(`.